# finding subsets dicretely c

Tags: c, discrete-mathematics

```
for (i = 0; i < (pow(2,n)-1); i++) {
    x = binary_conversion(i);
    for (j = (n-1); j > 0; j--) {

        if (x == 0) {
            M[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else {
            M[i][j] = x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

i want to print the subsets of a set, so for a set of n elements i get the value of 2^n. from 0 to 2^n, i'm converting the values to binary. and i am keeping the binary values in a matrice and as i go through the matrice, if the value is 1, i am printing the corresponding element of the original set.But while creating the matrice, it assigns the same binary value to two consecutive rows so at the end i can not even get half of the subsets. What do you think is wrong with the code?

Comment: Hint: don't use the `pow` function. See [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah because you don't cover the LSB or the 0th element. `for (j = (n-1); j >= 0; j--)` You missed the `=`.

Also you have to know if `j`-th bit is set in `i` or not.

And instead of pow you can simply use (`1<<n`)[Equivalent to `2^n`]

Your code is not readable. I will post the pseudocode.

```
for ( int i = 0; i<= (1<<numOfSetElmts)-1; i++)
{
     //print Subset-i
     for(int pos = 0; pos<=n-1;pos++)
       if( i&(1<<pos) )
         print Set[pos]
}
```

#### Why am I not using `pow`?

The pow function is implemented by an algorithm and uses floating point functions and values to compute the power value.

So power of floating point to the power `n` is not necessarily multiplying it repetitively n times. As a result you end up with some errors and execution is a bit slower too.

#### Bitwise is faster?

Yes it is. Even if modern implementation are making changes to the architecture as a whole but still you won't lose the performance by using bitwise. Most of them it will have better performance than addition operation, if not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your program have worst complexity. There are better solutions for this problem with minimum complexity. Anyway the problem of your code is put '<='

```
i <= pow(2,n)-1
```

Also you can use `i < 1<<n` Both work same but second one is better and faster. The same problem happens in the inner loop where you didn't put '=' sign. ie, `j>=0` . Else the program was good.

The better solution for your problem may look like this.

```
void subsets(char A[], int N)
{
    int i,j;
    for( i = 0;i < (1 << N); ++i)
    {
        for( j = 0;j < N;++j)
            if(i & (1 << j))
                printf("%c  ",  A[j] );
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In this there is no external binary conversion or matrix needed.

Comment: wow, thank you . I usually write the first solution that i can think of , and then try to improve it. So that would be a great improvement, i hope i'll get faster someday. Thanks again!